# How can I pass parameter for get() when I use generics

Tags: java, hibernate, session, generics

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    Generic<Customer> x = new Generic(Customer.class);
    Customer cust = x.get("1");
    System.out.println(cust.getFullname());
}


class Generic<T> {
private Class<T> clazz;

public Generic(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

public  Session openSession() {
    Configuration config = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();
    SessionFactory sf = config.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    return session;
}

public T get(String id) {
    Session session = openSession();
    T t = (T) session.get(clazz.getClass(), id);
    return t;
}
```

}

When i run this program it dont except my Customer.class(Customer is just an entity class) and throw exception
 org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Class.Please explain me why

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an additional Class object of type `Class<T>`.

Edit: I may be wrong, haven't used Hibernate for too long. Some versions of get() require a Class object.

Either way, look up the definition of Session.get [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html).

Comment: yeah, thanks anyway